# .htaccess how to make my URL shorter?

Tags: .htaccess, url

My current URL:

`http://localhost/vavis/public_html/index.html#/users`

I wan't to be like this:

```
http://localhost/users
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to rely on javascript or something on the client side to handle this. The "`/users`" part of the url is part of a fragment (after the "#") which isn't even sent to the server, so there's no way anything in the htaccess would know you were trying to access /users.

There's some more information about URL fragments here: https://www.oho.com/blog/explained-60-seconds-hash-symbols-urls-and-seo

So depending on how it got there and why you need it, it may not be as simple as simply removing it or encoding it into something else.